# Only allow whole numbers but display with '.' on the thousand for easy read

Tags: validation, google-sheets, format

I want to apply data validation to my column so as to only accept whole numbers.

However I want these to be displayed with a dot so as to make it easier to read later on.

e.g. input = 14354 which is valid and then displayed 14.354

the data validation regular expression I am ussing is:

```
=regexmatch(to_text(A2);"^\d+\.*\d+$")
```

and the custom formatting is:

```
#,##
```

for most this working fine, large numbers are displayed with the '.' and things it shouldnt accept it is rejecting.

However, in the case of numbers which are entered with a decimal point as these are hidden, it is accepting it as valid.

It is also changing the format to auto atic and reading as date such entries like: 15.4

I should point out that I am using sheets in spanish and therefore the , is the marker for decimal places.

What am i missing here??

Answer (score 1):

Select the cell range then go to Data > Data validation...

Add a custom formula rule:

`=mod(A1;1)=0`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
=and(regexmatch(to_text(A2);"^\d+(\.\d{3})*$");mod(A2;1)=0)
```

- Improved your formula to only accept a dot when it is followed by 3 numbers (this way, we invalidate the date e.g `A2`)
- Combining the improved formula of yours and Aresvik's modulo answer, we need to check if the value does not have decimal. (this way, we invalidate the decimal e.g `A6`)
- When both returns true, this shall confirm that the number inputted is a whole number with no decimal and not a date.

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Invalid inputted values:

- `A2` - `15.4`
- `A6` - `16412,212`